# Minimum material deposit threshold in slic3r

Tags: slicing, slic3r

I've been using Slic3r for a while now, and for the most part am happy with the results it produces. I mostly use the standard profiles provided by Prusa for my i3 mk3.

However, when watching the 3D printer at work, executing GCODE produced by Slic3r, I notice that frequently the printer makes large travel moves, deposits an absolutely tiny amount of material and does this several times in a row. Sometimes this is so small, barely any material actually comes out of the extruder. I'm convinced the end result would be no different if these operations were simply skipped. In some instances it might even improve print quality, due to reduced stringing.

It strikes me that print time and printer wear-and-tear could be significantly reduced if there was an option to simply skip deposits of material below a certain threshold of volume.

Despite having gone through all the Slic3r options, I've never found something which does this, unless there is a way to achieve it with some combination of settings which I have not understood.

My question is therefore: how can I tell Slic3r not to make individual material deposit moves, below a certain volume?

Answer (score 1):

It does this in small corners.

For example, [this model](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1226466), when sliced has this on layer ~7:
[image]
Tiny tiny bit of blue infill.

There seems to be no feature to explicitely disable this.
But sometimes an additional perimeter solves it.

Comment: Note, with a third perimeter, the printer would still come back to print this blue line - but as perimeter instead of as infill.